# Freeform not pulling some answers into notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform, email, notification, checkbox

Have an issue where I have added check boxes and radio buttons to a form but am having the results pull into the notification email correctly. Two Questions....

1. The check boxes are needed to allow "check that all apply" for the user. However, in the notification email is only showing the last item checked on the email.  So if a user checks Regional Driver, Local Driver and Warehouse...only Warehouse shows up on the form.  Here is the code I have for that...

How do I get the multiple selections to pull into the notification form?

> Interested In (Check All That Apply)
>
> OTR Driver/Regional Driver
>
> Local Driver
>
> Packer/Loader/Unloader
>
> Warehouse

2. Likewise, on my radio buttons it isn't pulling in the selection of Per Hour, Per Week, Per Month or Per Year into the from.  It is only showing the entry entered into the Salary Expectations box.  I have fields set up for "salary_expectations" and for "pay_rate".  How would I tie the radio buttons to the pay_rate field so that it pulls into the notification form?

> What are your salary requirements?
>
> Per Hour
>
> Per Week
>
> Per Month
>
> Per Year

Just in case the code isn't showing properly on here, I am adding a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, the issue is that you need to specify `[]` on the checkbox field names to accept more than one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interested_in[]" value="OTR Driver/Regional Driver" />
```

For #2, judging by the way you wrote your question and the screenshot of code (next time would be nicer to just include the actual code btw), I assume this is because you have the wrong field name specified. In your question you say the field is named `pay_rate`, but your template code uses `help_packing`.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved problem number 1 and I am now pulling all answers into the notification email.  Still not seeing payrate on the salary and I have it set to the correct code.

Comment: What does your template code look like now?

Comment: GOT IT FIXED!  WHEW!  Thanks!